# Twitter search terms does not show bot-account tweets?

Tags: twitter, twitter-search

I want to make a specific search-term in Twitter, this search-term does include tweets from bot-account(s).

However, the search function from twitter does not include tweets from bot-accounts?

I already disabled the Quality filter in Settings.

Any suggestions regarding my problem?

Also: when forcing by from:xxx it is still not include in the results.

Comment: How do you define what a "bot account" is? What searches are you performing?

Comment: Twitter is filtering certain account for search terms, using the new quality filter. Filtered accounts are most of the time auto-posting accounts, like bots. It's not mine account, so I cannot change it, however I want to include these bot-accounts in my search terms.